# Cannot post a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, captcha

It keeps saying "Oops, robot detection failed" after I fill out the CAPTCHA (the green check shows). I receive the same error in incognito.

I cannot fill out the help form on the *Contact Us* page either (for the same reason).

I am using Chrome, and trust me, I am not a robot.

Comment: Exactly what a robot would say. And we just can't have the robots posting questions any time they want, right?

Comment: *I am not a robot* --> so what is the result of four + 5?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Forty-5 right?

Comment: @Nick yeah, you are a *smart* robot ;)

Comment: Uber meta dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352994/stackoverflow-captcha-check-fails-oops-robot-detection-failed - Might be a genuine problem

Comment: Should be fixed. Can you try again?

Comment: I have to wait for the 90min timer between posting questions to go away, but I will try again once I can

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To quote from his MSE response, [Mark stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352995/284336):

> Short version: we fat-fingered something while doing some routine settings maintenance, which meant that for the "captcha keys" setting (and only this setting), we had setting values for every environment except "production". And of course, all the tests passed just fine until it hit your good selves, and there were no keys available to talk to the captcha server with.
>
> Remedied. Sorry about the inconvenience, and thanks for reporting it.